# Series divergence of a limit of a sequence of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Title a bit confusing, here is a clear idea of the question:

> Let $(x_n^i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $(x^i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be sequences, such that for all $i$, $x_n^i\to x^i$ as $n\to\infty$. Suppose that for all $n$, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_n^i| = \infty$ (here $x_n^i$ is not the $i$-th power).

Does this necessarily mean that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}|x^i| = \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $x_n^i=\frac{1}{i+n-1}$ for $i,n\geq 1$. That is, $\{x_1^i\}$ is the sequence
$$ 1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots $$
$\{x_2^i\}$ is the sequence
$$ \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4} $$
and so on. Then 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_n^i=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i+n-1}=\infty$$
for each $n$, but $x^i=0$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$x_n^i=\begin{cases}0, & n\le i,\\ 1, & n>i.\end{cases}$$

What do you get?